# Partial stash/commit in one session

Tags: git

Is there a way to do a combination of "git add -p" and "git stash -p"?

Let's say you're doing "git add -p", and find a chunk you want to *stash* and not just "skip for now".

An example could be: you've done some changes that you want to make multiple commits from. A few of the changes, however, should not be part of any of the commits you're currently making (a specific example in my case is a change to one of the files in the `.vscode` folder).

Instead of having to do `git stash -p` first and then `git add -p`, is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

The letter `s` is even available. Imagine:

```
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? ?
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
s - stash this hunk instead
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Comment: Git is open source; if you want to add features, you can clone it and hack away. I personally recommend *avoiding* `git stash` as much as possible myself though.

Comment: @torek: would you mind explaining what you prefer to do instead?

Comment: Is the frequency of that scenario (`add -p` with some chunks to be stashed) high enough for you to discard the solution you mentioned (`stash -p` beforehand)? I, for one, find it too low to slightly clutter the `add --patch` mode UI with an additional option for stash.

Comment: @RomainValeri: what I actually end up doing in practice is to just skip the same chunks each time I do `add -p`. :)

Comment: Just make commits. If you find that you need to break up commits, it means you aren't committing often enough; do it more often, until you don't find this need any more.

Comment: @torek: you're probably right :)